# pyo3 getting started example not building on MacOS

Tags: rust, interop

I'm trying to get started with py03, using the starter project ***created by maturin*** as described here:

https://pyo3.rs/v0.17.3/

However, when I try to build it, I get this at the link phase:

```
  = note: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
            "_PyBytes_AsString", referenced from:
                pyo3::types::bytes::PyBytes::as_bytes::hb0ce42a9e99b7119 in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.13.rcgu.o)
            "_PyBytes_Size", referenced from:
                pyo3::types::bytes::PyBytes::as_bytes::hb0ce42a9e99b7119 in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.13.rcgu.o)
            "_PyCFunction_NewEx", referenced from:
                pyo3::types::function::PyCFunction::internal_new_from_pointers::h92a1006a066f3794 in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.5.rcgu.o)
            "_PyErr_Fetch", referenced from:
                pyo3::err::PyErr::take::h34abf03aae524a39 in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.2.rcgu.o)
            "_PyErr_GivenExceptionMatches", referenced from:
                pyo3::err::PyErr::is_instance::h5bd7a1c534dc95ff in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.2.rcgu.o)
            "_PyErr_NewExceptionWithDoc", referenced from:
                pyo3::err::PyErr::new_type::h207f67133d2fe7dc in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.2.rcgu.o)
            "_PyErr_NormalizeException", referenced from:
                pyo3::err::PyErr::make_normalized::h92e97061454d87df in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.2.rcgu.o)
            "_PyErr_Print", referenced from:
                pyo3::err::panic_after_error::h1855c4e68479b292 in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.2.rcgu.o)
            "_PyErr_PrintEx", referenced from:
                pyo3::err::PyErr::take::h34abf03aae524a39 in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.2.rcgu.o)
            "_PyErr_Restore", referenced from:
                pyo3::err::PyErr::take::h34abf03aae524a39 in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.2.rcgu.o)
                pyo3::err::PyErr::restore::h79045018546bf3d0 in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.2.rcgu.o)
            "_PyEval_SaveThread", referenced from:
                pyo3::gil::prepare_freethreaded_python::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::h7ec7eff51d016eb2 in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.8.rcgu.o)
            "_PyExc_AttributeError", referenced from:
                _$LT$pyo3..exceptions..PyAttributeError$u20$as$u20$pyo3..type_object..PyTypeInfo$GT$::type_object_raw::h9d284f308c6428d1 in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.1.rcgu.o)
            "_PyExc_BaseException", referenced from:
                _$LT$pyo3..exceptions..PyBaseException$u20$as$u20$pyo3..type_object..PyTypeInfo$GT$::type_object_raw::hbc1c2918865ca2cb in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.1.rcgu.o)
            "_PyExc_ImportError", referenced from:
                _$LT$pyo3..exceptions..PyImportError$u20$as$u20$pyo3..type_object..PyTypeInfo$GT$::type_object_raw::h61f161f64a44efc1 in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.1.rcgu.o)
            "_PyExc_OverflowError", referenced from:
                _$LT$pyo3..exceptions..PyOverflowError$u20$as$u20$pyo3..type_object..PyTypeInfo$GT$::type_object_raw::h745fe716930d7217 in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.1.rcgu.o)
            "_PyExc_TypeError", referenced from:
                _$LT$pyo3..exceptions..PyTypeError$u20$as$u20$pyo3..type_object..PyTypeInfo$GT$::type_object_raw::h53ec02261503227a in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.1.rcgu.o)
            "_PyExc_ValueError", referenced from:
                _$LT$pyo3..exceptions..PyValueError$u20$as$u20$pyo3..type_object..PyTypeInfo$GT$::type_object_raw::h6af62b63d19decb7 in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.1.rcgu.o)
            "_PyException_GetCause", referenced from:
                pyo3::err::PyErr::cause::h53aeaff8e297ea33 in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.2.rcgu.o)
            "_PyException_SetCause", referenced from:
                pyo3::err::PyErr::set_cause::hf1c8ca56b45e01b9 in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.2.rcgu.o)
            "_PyGILState_Ensure", referenced from:
                pyo3::gil::GILGuard::acquire_unchecked::h9d0224a43e6401ff in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.8.rcgu.o)
            "_PyGILState_Release", referenced from:
                _$LT$pyo3..gil..GILGuard$u20$as$u20$core..ops..drop..Drop$GT$::drop::h37927fc149066dfd in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.8.rcgu.o)
            "_PyList_Append", referenced from:
                pyo3::types::list::PyList::append::h9a6d00903059b938 in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.15.rcgu.o)
            "_PyList_New", referenced from:
                pyo3::types::list::PyList::empty::h5be9ffe49a8635cc in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.15.rcgu.o)
            "_PyLong_AsUnsignedLongLong", referenced from:
                pyo3::types::num::_$LT$impl$u20$pyo3..conversion..FromPyObject$u20$for$u20$u64$GT$::extract::hc3c373b6f4fdef2b in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.5.rcgu.o)
            "_PyModule_Create2", referenced from:
                pyo3_ffi::modsupport::PyModule_Create::ha69b3fe4e6294f16 in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.7.rcgu.o)
            "_PyModule_GetName", referenced from:
                pyo3::types::module::PyModule::name::h9e36dc62b552af10 in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.4.rcgu.o)
            "_PyNumber_Index", referenced from:
                pyo3::types::num::_$LT$impl$u20$pyo3..conversion..FromPyObject$u20$for$u20$u64$GT$::extract::hc3c373b6f4fdef2b in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.5.rcgu.o)
            "_PyObject_GetAttr", referenced from:
                pyo3::types::any::PyAny::getattr::h2e27ff38c6c3fa19 in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.6.rcgu.o)
            "_PyObject_Repr", referenced from:
                pyo3::types::any::PyAny::repr::h269b96ae0d11be7c in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.6.rcgu.o)
            "_PyObject_SetAttr", referenced from:
                pyo3::types::any::PyAny::setattr::he6a247c2d4d07938 in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.6.rcgu.o)
                pyo3::types::any::PyAny::setattr::hfd8996f03911a84a in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.6.rcgu.o)
            "_PyObject_Str", referenced from:
                pyo3::types::any::PyAny::str::he0298d3bd0b3ac1e in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.6.rcgu.o)
            "_PyTuple_New", referenced from:
                pyo3::types::tuple::_$LT$impl$u20$pyo3..conversion..IntoPy$LT$pyo3..instance..Py$LT$pyo3..types..any..PyAny$GT$$GT$$u20$for$u20$$LP$T0$C$$RP$$GT$::into_py::h9b62fef051255294 in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.15.rcgu.o)
                pyo3::types::tuple::_$LT$impl$u20$pyo3..conversion..IntoPy$LT$pyo3..instance..Py$LT$pyo3..types..any..PyAny$GT$$GT$$u20$for$u20$$LP$T0$C$$RP$$GT$::into_py::hf65fb0560a71d6f9 in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.8.rcgu.o)
            "_PyTuple_SetItem", referenced from:
                pyo3::types::tuple::_$LT$impl$u20$pyo3..conversion..IntoPy$LT$pyo3..instance..Py$LT$pyo3..types..any..PyAny$GT$$GT$$u20$for$u20$$LP$T0$C$$RP$$GT$::into_py::h9b62fef051255294 in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.15.rcgu.o)
                pyo3::types::tuple::_$LT$impl$u20$pyo3..conversion..IntoPy$LT$pyo3..instance..Py$LT$pyo3..types..any..PyAny$GT$$GT$$u20$for$u20$$LP$T0$C$$RP$$GT$::into_py::hf65fb0560a71d6f9 in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.8.rcgu.o)
            "_PyUnicode_AsEncodedString", referenced from:
                pyo3::types::string::PyString::to_string_lossy::h5fff290c6902d849 in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.2.rcgu.o)
            "_PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize", referenced from:
                pyo3::types::string::PyString::to_str::he285678de3416a4a in pyo3_example.31e4txws67eg8xfh.rcgu.o
                pyo3::types::string::PyString::to_str::h0c0d3cfa46a3349a in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.2.rcgu.o)
            "_PyUnicode_FromStringAndSize", referenced from:
                pyo3::types::string::PyString::new::h756c302dc780d638 in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.2.rcgu.o)
                pyo3::types::string::PyString::intern::h99c7d7fb8d5ff249 in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.2.rcgu.o)
            "_PyUnicode_InternInPlace", referenced from:
                pyo3::types::string::PyString::intern::h99c7d7fb8d5ff249 in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.2.rcgu.o)
            "_Py_InitializeEx", referenced from:
                pyo3::gil::prepare_freethreaded_python::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::h7ec7eff51d016eb2 in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.8.rcgu.o)
            "_Py_IsInitialized", referenced from:
                pyo3::gil::prepare_freethreaded_python::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::h7ec7eff51d016eb2 in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.8.rcgu.o)
                pyo3::gil::GILGuard::acquire::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::hcf818b25afc19e8c in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.8.rcgu.o)
            "__Py_Dealloc", referenced from:
                pyo3_ffi::object::Py_DECREF::h80a00bbd387b4f47 in libpyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.rlib(pyo3-fe99c63bd9fc0ad2.pyo3.754cfbf6-cgu.4.rcgu.o)
          ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
          clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What could be going on here? And I'm wondering whether there is a working pyo3 example I could use as a starter project

Comment: Looks like you're missing some library, make sure python is installed and can be found by the linker.

Comment: Yes it does look like a library issue, but there is no indication which library that I can see, and no complaint about not being able to find a library. And yes, I have a few python 3.8 (Anaconda) venvs. @cafce25. It's as if the cargo build process isn't calling out the library, and I am new enough to Rust not to be too conversant with the cargo build system. Plus it is an out of the box example project generated by maturin, so it should "just work"

Answer (score 2):

Just to confirm and expand a little bit to the answer from [Andrew Voelkel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74452311/pyo3-getting-started-example-not-building-on-macos#:%7E:text=at%200%3A00-,Andrew%20Voelkel,-5154).

According to the error's output I personally got (macOS Sonoma 14.0):

> = note: ld: warning: no platform load command found in '/private/var/folders/rm/4t99t9dj0b5dg7h1mndxk0hc0000gp/T/rustce8T2Oc/symbols.o', assuming: macOS

In macOS the platform needs to be explicitly specified, thus, you need to create `.cargo/config`, which means in the .cargo folder create a `config` (no extension) file, and, write the following content:

```html
[target.x86_64-apple-darwin]
rustflags = [
  "-C", "link-arg=-undefined",
  "-C", "link-arg=dynamic_lookup",
]

[target.aarch64-apple-darwin]
rustflags = [
  "-C", "link-arg=-undefined",
  "-C", "link-arg=dynamic_lookup",
]
```

By specifying `x86_64-apple-darwin`, then you can consider to be *guaranteed to work* according to the official [platform-support](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/platform-support.html) but for some reason, you have to include the `target.aarch64-apple-darwin` as well, otherwise it throws the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the documentation was out of date, there are several differing versions of the instructions. These work as of this date:

https://rustrepo.com/repo/PyO3-PyO3-rust-foreign-function-interface